# Is there a way to see the time that a photo was taken on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos

Sometimes I took a photo using my iPhone, and then later on, I wonder how long I have been there at that location, I thought of checking when the last photo was taken, and can tell the time when I arrived, but I found it wasn't easily possible to see what time the photo was taken.

Is there really a way to see the time that photo was taken, be it 1 hour and 20 minutes ago, without using any third party app and without importing the photo to a computer?  I thought this might be a simple photo info thing that might be invoked by some easy way?

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/will-my-iphone-show-me-the-date-stamp-of-a-photo). The answer seems to be not without a 3rd party app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - the old mobile [iPhoto app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iphoto/id497786065?mt=8) as well as the Photos app shows all sorts of photo metadata (assuming you allowed the camera app to store it in the first place) including the capture time.

[image]

Camera roll and Photo stream are part of the Library, so you should be good to go. You can get the above screen by tapping the i with the rectangle to bring up the information for photos stored in the library.

[image: info button in iPhoto mobile]

In the case of time, even if you deny location services, it should have the timestamp based on the file's creation date/time.

Comment: looks cool... except it costs US$4.99 to buy?  I just hoped to see the timestamp and that's it...

Comment: There are other apps like [Camera Awesome](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/camera-awesome/id420744028?mt=8) that purport to do the same for free, but I haven't used it.

Comment: Exif viewer by Fluntro have free app and paid app. Here is link to free app https://appsto.re/us/y71w6.i

Answer (score 9):

You are not missing anything, the iPhone has no mechanism to see that information natively. However, if you search for EXIF on the App Store, there are a few (some free) apps that will happily do that in the device itself.

You must note that, due to the way iTunes work, pictures coming from iTunes will **not** have their metadata associated. Sad but true.

Answer (score 7):

To view the [EXIF](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/exif-iptc-metadata-browser/id383576492?mt=8) data (time taken, GPS coordinates, and other values) of your photos on the iPhone you will need a 3'rd party application. I could only find these two on the app store:

- [Exif & IPTC Metadata Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/exif-iptc-metadata-browser/id383576492?mt=8)
- [Exif Wizard](http://itunes.apple.com/app/exif-wizard/id387652357?mt=8)

Comment: Wow, that Exif Wizard is sweet as hell!  Thanks a ton for that helpful link, I can't believe Apple doesn't have that functionality built into the OS by default.

Comment: Also checkout "Exif Viewer by fluntro" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aLHWjPyfOY

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with the built in Photos app. Open the photo and observe the date and time shown in the navigation bar at the top. This only works if you hold the phone in portrait mode (vertical)!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

iPhoto for iPhone will also show you this along with many other details about the photo (ISO, shutter speed, etc) if you prefer to stick with Apple written applications.

I have started to use iPhoto as a replacement for Photos on my iPhone!

Answer (score 3):

As on iOS 11.0 or later, You can view time stamp of photo within **Apple's Photos App** without Third party Apps.
Note that, if it doesn't display the Year, that photo was shot on same year.

But it doesn't display "seconds" field in time stamp, so if you need that level of details, checkout Third party "EXIF" apps on Appstore, like "EXIF Viewer by Fluntro"

[image]
[image: enter imagex description here]

**Screenshot using EXIF Viewer by Fluntro.**

[image]

Disclaimer: I have developed the EXIF Viewer by Fluntro App :)

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/exif-viewer-by-fluntro/id944118456?mt=8

To know more features about the app, checkout
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycz0b0uDn9A

Answer (score 2):

The free app [Camera Awesome](http://www.awesomize.com/) allows you to see when a photo was taken.

Open the app and go to the camera roll. Tap the plus button and import the photo you want to view date information for. Select that photo and tap the `(i)` button. The date and time the photo was taken will be displayed, as well as lots of other useful details.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see what time it was taken without an app, you could simply open the image on a computer using a notepad program of some sort. The time and date will often be within the first few lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

**Rotate your iPhone.** The built-in Photos app shows the date and time the photo was taken in the navigation bar at the top, but only in portrait orientation.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking on App Store for EXIF, also search for term 'metadata'... there is a free app named 'Photo Metadata Viewer' from Boxo (??) that dumps this info to screen for fairly easy reading. NOT fancy, but free.

Answer (score 1):

Some other camera apps give access to EXIF data. Camera+, for example, has an info button in its lightbox picture-viewer which shows EXIF data and even shows a map detailing where that picture was taken.

Note this is helpful even if you're looking for EXIF data in photos taken with standard iOS photo services, embedded in some other app, as Camera+ can import images from the iPhone's standard Camera Roll.

(I have no connection to Camera+ except as a satisfied user)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably other apps, but [ProCamera](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/procamera/id300216827?mt=8) has this ability.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A **free**, lightweight app for this is [Exif Wizard](http://itunes.apple.com/app/exif-wizard/id387652357?mt=8) (size 0.2 MB).

If you only want to access the timestamp or other Exif data, it makes more sense to install Exif Wizard instead of e.g. [Camera Awesome](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/camera-awesome/id420744028?ls=1&mt=8) (18.1 MB) or [ProCamera](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/procamera/id300216827?mt=8) (17.4 MB).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another third party solution (of which I feel obliged to confess I created) is [Photo Timestamps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-timestamps/id839920232?mt=8%E2%80%8E). It's an elegant solution to this problem- it displays your photos in a 3 photo grid with the timestamp displayed over the photo's thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

We just released a new app that makes it easy to sort, organize and share your iOS photos by date and location.

Photowerks scans your camera roll and displays your photos similarly to the Apple Photos app, but groups them by date taken or photo location.

Features:

- Quickly sort photos by date taken, city, state, country, camera make, or camera model.
- View photos in a grid or list view.
- Tap photo to view date taken and location (city, state)
- Share photos via email, Facebook, Twitter (with photo captions listing photo date and location)
- Create new albums in the Apple Photos app.
- View photo details with standard pinch to zoom gestures and swipe to view previous/next photo.

The app is USD $0.99 on [the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photowerks/id643351365?mt=8).

Answer (score 0):

Photo Timestamps is a third party app that provides this information. It's not free, but it's also not $4.99. It's got a really clean, minimal interface (obligatory disclosure: I made it).

Answer (score 0):

Since this took me awhile to find and a few of the apps here are old I thought I would share several iphone date viewing apps.

The ones I have tried:

**Exif Wizard**

Good app that I have used for about 2 years. Nothing fancy it just lets you view the metadata. It is only 0.4 MB.

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/exif-wizard/id387652357?mt=8

**Koredoko - Exif and GPS Viewer**

Good app that I have used for about 2 years. Nothing fancy it just lets you view the metadata. It is only 4.5 MB.

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/koredoko-exif-and-gps-viewer/id286765236?mt=8

**Camera Awesome**

Ok app. It is 48.5 MB. It doesn't do anything exciting to me. I rather use the regular camera app for taking pictures instead of this because of the size. It can view metadata.

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/camera-awesome/id420744028?mt=8

The ones I have not tried:

**Flickd**

Size: 0.3 MB

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flickd/id305580150?mt=8

**Photo Date**

Size: 3.4 MB

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-date/id605218393?mt=8

**Photo Investigator: View, Edit, Remove Metadata; GPS, EXIF...**

Size: 3.5 MB

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-investigator-view-edit/id571574618?mt=8

**Pixelgarde**

Size: 4.8 MB

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pixelgarde-photo-privacy-editor/id414677492?mt=8

**Metadata Cut - View and Remove Metadata**

Size: 21.5 MB

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/metadata-cut-view-remove-metadata/id568689108?mt=8

Answer (score -1):

[My Photo date](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-photo-date/id698365018?mt=8) will allow you to do that.

Comment: Seems like someone downvoted without a comment. Anyway, your answer is not pertinent to this question. This is about finding the date a photo was taken, whereas your answer is about printing the date on the photo while the photo is being taken.